# How do you set the message body for a POST request in a rails test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to set the POST body to an arbitrary string in my integration test. My code:

```
@request.env['RAW_POST_DATA'] = "testing 1 2 3"
post '/receiver'
```

I am supposed to see "testing 1 2 3" in the controller when I do a:

```
foo = request.body.read
```

But "request" yields nil. Does anyone know how to make the rails integration test pass "testing 1 2 3" to the raw message body?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are doing an integration test I would just use the capybara gem to pass a post request. If you have a field where you can fill in the variable to be posted you can specify that in capybara, otherwise you could just pass an arbitrary variable as long as it passes strong parameters in your controller.

For example this code sends a post request using Rspec and Capybara

```
def test_create_account_as(email, password)
  visit new_user_registration_path
  fill_in "user_email", with: email
  fill_in "user_password", with: password
  fill_in "user_password_confirmation", with: password
  click_button "Sign up"
end
```